# PHP SQL search result as POST / GET link

Tags: php, mysql, sql, post, get

I have problems to get the right GET-method for my results.

I have a script which shows me some results of my database. It works with Ajax:

```
$suchbegriff = $_POST["suchbegriff"];

    if ($_POST["suchbegriff"]){

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE vorname OR nachname LIKE '%$suchbegriff%'";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        echo "<br>Sie suchten nach: ".$suchbegriff."<br>";

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {   echo "<form action=\"profil.php\" method=\"get\">".$row['nachname'];
            echo $row['vorname']."</a> <input type=\"submit\">";
            echo "<br/>";} 
    }
```

Now I want to get the ID of the search-results to bring it with GET/POST to an other page called profil.php (unique user-profile):

```
 <div class="col-xl-12">
        <div class="col-xl-2">
            <p>Vorname</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-5">
            <p><?php
                $sql = "SELECT vorname FROM user WHERE ID = $_GET[nachname]";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);
                $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
                echo $row['vorname'];
                ?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Is there a way to couple *nachname* and *vorname* (name, surname) in the SQL-Statement?
And how can I get the **unique profile-URL** from the search-results?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking. Are you asking how to get both the nachname and the vorname from the same SQL statement? Or are you asking how to display them both? Or something else entirely?

Comment: I have a list of names as result. I want to make a button after each result. After a click the userprofile of this result have to open. But I don't know, how to get the ID of each result and how I can transfer it to profil.php.

Comment: I don't think you need a form with method GET in your while loop. You should be able to use a simple URL to pass information from one page to another. That is how GET works.

Comment: So change the while loop to display a list of URLs. When someone clicks on one of those links, it takes them to the corresponding profil.php page where you display additional information based on the parameters you get from the URL.

Comment: Your `WHERE` is wrong. It should be `WHERE vorname LIKE '%$suchbegriff%' OR nachname LIKE '%$suchbegriff%'"

Comment: I removed [fixed] from the title. If an answer was posted that fixed it, accepting it marks the question as fixed/solution. There's no need to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Change your first script to print a list of anchors, and put the ID into the `href` URL.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{   
    echo "<a href=\"profil.php?nachname=".$row['id'].\">".$row['nachname']. " ".$row['vorname']."</a>";
    echo "<br/>";
}
```